# Editor Tracking ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, editing

I have created specific fields for 'Creator', 'Create Date', 'Editor' and 'Date Edited' and have enabled Editor Tracking on these fields. Whenever I add an attribute, my username and the date are populated in all four fields. Why is this happening? It should only be populating my 'Creator' and 'Create Date' upon feature creation, and only populate the 'Editor' and 'Date Edited' once that feature gets edited, correct?

Comment: I may be mistaken, but I thought the initial feature creation populated both creator and editor. Then subsequent edits tracked just the edit portion. Might be worth a try.

Comment: Thank you for your answer MapHound. Yes this is what has been happening to me. I was mistaken in thinking it would populate one or the other.

Answer (score 1):

Creation is an edit. This saves you from needing to query both if you're only interested in the last time that anything was done to the record. After creation, any subsequent edits will yield a change to the Date Edited values.

Comment: Mark it then as solution, please.